# Googol charts: how to use getcharttype()

Tags: javascript, methods, google-visualization

Thank you for your answer... I'm ALMOST there :) I declared wrapper as global var, I used the getChartType method but still I'm not getting what I need.

so I have these 2 functions now:

```
var wrapper

function loadEditor() {
  // Create the chart to edit.
  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

if (sorttest == 1) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTableA01?>)
} else {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTableB01?>)
}



  wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({

     dataTable: data,
     left:1,
     options: {
     'chartArea': {width: '60%', left: 45},
     'legend' :'none',

     'title':'Number of Newly Opened Roles per <?echo $_SESSION['Display']?>'
     }

  });


  chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', redrawChart);
  chartEditor.openDialog(wrapper, {});
 }

 function sortABC() {

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
 var CurrChartType = wrapper.getChartType();
sorttest = 1;

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTableA01?>);
 var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': CurrChartType,
     dataTable: data,
     left:1,
     options: {
     'chartArea': {width: '60%', left: 45},
     'legend' :'none',

     'title':'Number of Newly Opened Roles per <?echo $_SESSION['Display']?>'
     } 
  });
```

I  get an error on the 2nd line of sortABC()

```
     var CurrChartType = wrapper.getChartType();
```

but have no idea why...

please help Bro.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the chart type using  `google.visualization.ChartWrapper.getChartType` method. In your case you could declare `wrapper` as global variable (it will be initialized once  `google.visualization.ChartWrapper` is created) to make it accessible in `sortABC` function. Then you could get current chart type.

The following example demonstrates how to get/set `chart type` of Google Chart.

**Complete example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.0', { packages: ['charteditor'] });
google.setOnLoadCallback(loadEditor);
var chartEditor = null;
var wrapper = null;

function loadEditor() {
    // Create the chart to edit.
    wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'LineChart',
        'dataSourceUrl': 'http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=pCQbetd-CptGXxxQIG7VFIQ&pub=1',
        'query': 'SELECT A,D WHERE D > 100 ORDER BY D',
        'options': { 'title': 'Population Density (people/km^2)', 'legend': 'none' }
    });

    chartEditor = new google.visualization.ChartEditor();
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartEditor, 'ok', redrawChart);
    chartEditor.openDialog(wrapper, {});
}

// On "OK" save the chart to a <div> on the page.
function redrawChart() {
    chartEditor.getChartWrapper().draw(document.getElementById('vis_div'));
    initChartPanel();
}



function initChartPanel() {
    document.getElementById('chartpanel_div').style.visibility = 'visible';
    var chartTypes = chartEditor.getChartTypes();
    var select = document.getElementById('charttypes_select');
    for (var i = 0; i < chartTypes.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = chartTypes[i];
        opt.value = chartTypes[i];
        select.appendChild(opt);
    }
    document.getElementById('chart_info').innerHTML = wrapper.getChartType();
}


function changeChartType(sel) {
    var chartType = sel.value;
    wrapper.setChartType(chartType);
    wrapper.draw(document.getElementById('vis_div'));
    document.getElementById('chart_info').innerHTML = wrapper.getChartType();
}
```

```css
 #chart_info {
            font-weight: bold;
 }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div class="chart_panel" id="chartpanel_div" style=" visibility: hidden" >
            <select id="charttypes_select" onchange="changeChartType(this)"></select>
            Current Chart Type:<span id="chart_info"></span>
</div>
          
<div id="vis_div" style="height: 400px; width: 600px;"></div>
```